# MacBook keyboard decals without letters

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking for one of these types of stylish MacBook keyboard skins:

[image]
[image]

But I don't want any of the keys marked. I just want blank keys, without letters/symbols.

Do any such products exist? I can't find any by looking myself.

Comment: My suggestion is that you contact the manufacturer of the keyboard skin that you are interested in and see if they can do one offs or custom orders.

Comment: @Allan that's probably going to be extremely expensive. I can't imagine that there aren't already soltions available, perhaps for touch typists to practice.

Comment: "Probably?" The response I give my employees when they tell me that is "probably means you haven't checked."  However, why not get [keyboard blanks](https://goo.gl/Qtpvai) and then put your skin on top of it?

Comment: @Allan the skins with designs look opaque.

Comment: So...you haven't checked then.  And for the record, you would be incorrect because those who consider me "crappy" do so elsewhere and for someone else.  Sort of like how this question gets ***voted*** closed....

Comment: @Allan Ooh ouch, but also like how it's gotten 2 upvotes and 0 downvotes

Comment: @owlswipe Yeah..that was a bit snarky... but it's one of those things that really irks me.  It's a "good question" in and of itself, but nonetheless, off topic as written....

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with customer support. Nor do I feel that it will attract spam/opinionated answers. I feel that the problem is already clearly described, and what I have done so far is stated. I don't understand why this is closed.

Comment: @theonlygusti Think it's closed because it's a product recommendation request, which can generate innumerable correct answers if multiple products exist. That's why this site is better suited to specific questions about Apple Hardware like "My iPhone is in a bootloop, what do I do?" rather than "Which case should I get for x need" (which can have multiple answers that are corrected based on opinion rather than based on whether they actually solve the problem of your bootloop.

Comment: @theonlygusti But you can ask a question on Meta about this.

Answer (score -2):

Yes,
There is one such unlabeled keyboard available that I have found: the [Das Keyboard 4 Ultimate](http://www.daskeyboard.com/daskeyboard-4-ultimate/). It is an external keyboard and not a cover, but I think it's what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: The OP said he was looking for a "keyboard skin" not an "external keyboard"